# Let $U\subset Y$ be open in $(Y,d_Y)$, where $d_Y:Y\times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the metric induced by $(X,d)$. Is $ U$ also open in $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $Y\subset X$.

Let $U\subset Y$ be open in $(Y,d_Y)$, where $d_Y:Y\times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the metric induced by $(X,d)$.

Is $ U$ then also inevitably open in $X$? If not, why?

Thoughts:

If $U$ is open in $(Y,d_Y)$ but not open in $(X,d)$ then there exists an $a\in U$ such that for every $r>0$:

$U_r(a)|_{d_Y}\subset U$ and $U_r(a)|_{d_X}\not\subset U$

with $U_r(a)|_{d_Y}=\{ y\in Y| d_Y(a,y)<r\}$ and $U_r(a)|_{d_X}=\{ x\in X| d(a,x)<r\}$

Comment: In $X = \mathbb R$ with the distance given by the absolute value, $U = [0, 1]$ is open in $Y = [0, 1]$ but not in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: What if $Y=\Bbb R\times \{0\}\subset\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: @Zag $Y\setminus U=\emptyset$ but I read that $\emptyset$ is open and closed in a topological space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set#Examples . So I don't see why I could assum $U$ to be open in $Y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This holds only if $Y$ is an open subset of $X$.**

To see it, consider any point $a \in U$. Since $U$ is open in $Y$, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $U$ contains the open $\varepsilon$-ball  in $Y$ about $a$, i.e.
$$
  U \supset B_{\varepsilon,Y}(a) = \{y\in Y: d(y,a)<\varepsilon\}.
$$
However, as $Y$ is open in $X$ and $a\in Y$, there exists $\varepsilon' >0$ such that
$$
  Y \supset B_{\varepsilon',X}(a) = \{x\in X: d(x,a)<\varepsilon\}.
$$
So for any $z\in X$ with $d(z,a)<\delta:=\min\{\varepsilon,\varepsilon'\}$, $z \in U$. In summary, for every $a\in U$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $U$ contains the open ball in $X$ about $a$.  Consequently, $U$ is open in $X$.

To see that your claim does not hold without other assumptions, consider $U=Y={x} \in X$. Then $U$ is open in $Y$, but unless there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_{\varepsilon,X}(x)=\{x\}$ (which is true for all the standard metrics except for the discrete metric), then $U$ is not open in $X$.

Comment: Thanks, Is $ U=Y=\{x\}\subset X$ really open in Y? "a set is closed if it contains the limit of any convergent sequence within it". That seems to be the case for $Y=\{x\}$, if $x$ is a fixed value.

Comment: Exactly, a constant sequence converges to the constant itself.

Comment: But then $U=Y$ doesn't seem like a good example for my question because it is not equivalent to $U$ is open. $U$ would be both open and closed.

Answer (score 1):

A necessary (and in fact sufficient) condition for every open subset of $Y$ to be open in $X$ is that $Y$ itself be open in $X.$

Answer (score 0):

No. Let $X = \mathbb R$ with $d(a,b) = \lvert a - b \rvert$ and $Y =\{0\}$. Then $Y$ is open in $Y$, but not open in $X$.

Comment: Is $Y=\{0\} $ really open in $Y$? "a set is closed if it contains the limit of any convergent sequence within it". That seems to be the case for $Y=\{0\} $

Comment: The entire set $Y$ is always both open and closed in $Y$.